# How to load a video from url during AR core session in UNITY3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, arcore

I've been facing a challenge, while trying to load a video from url during augmented reality session with AR core.

Previously I've been using videos locally placed in the folder, but I want to optimize the size of the app, that's why I need to use URLs.

This is the code I've been using for URLs which does not want to play the video:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using GoogleARCore;


public class ScreenV : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField] string[] _VideoURLs;
public AugmentedImage Image;
private VideoPlayer videoPlayer;



void Start()
{
    videoPlayer = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.Url;
    
}

void Update()
{
    if (Session.Status != SessionStatus.Tracking) 
        return;

    if (Image == null || Image.TrackingState != TrackingState.Tracking)
    {

        return;
    }

    
    if (Image != null || Image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
        {
        videoPlayer.url = _VideoURLs[Image.DatabaseIndex];
        videoPlayer.Play();
        }
    
    

    transform.localScale = new Vector3(Image.ExtentX, Image.ExtentZ, 1);
}
```

Previously I have been using similar lines of code playing video clips in augmented reality which worked with no problems.

```
public class ScreenV : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField] VideoClip[] _Clips;
public AugmentedImage Image;
private VideoPlayer videoPlayer;



void Start()
{
    videoPlayer = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;
    
}

void Update()
{
    if (Session.Status != SessionStatus.Tracking) 
        return;

    if (Image == null || Image.TrackingState != TrackingState.Tracking)
    {

        return;
    }

    
    if (Image != null || Image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
        {
        videoPlayer.clip = _Clips[Image.DatabaseIndex];
        videoPlayer.Play();
        }
    
    

    transform.localScale = new Vector3(Image.ExtentX, Image.ExtentZ, 1);
}
```

I've tried to just get the url in the start phase which worked fine, so the AR session can play video from url.

```
void Start()
{
    videoPlayer = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.Url;
    videoPlayer.url = _VideoURLs[5];
    
}
```

However, I need to index URLs based on what image is tracked, so it needs to be in update loop.

Does anyone have some idea why the AR session does not want to load the video from the url in the the update loop?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello Tomas, did you find a solution for this issue?